# Cordova/Ionic CLI how to update only www folder in assets

Tags: cordova, jenkins, ionic-framework

I have a problem with cordova www folder with android platform.

In my project i use cordova only for UI and I add legacy modules in Android studio (by changing something in gradles)

files tracked in repository don't include "platforms\android\assets\www" files.

I try to build my application on Jenkins via gradle. 
I can't use cordova prepare android command because this command overwrite my build gradle and setting gradle files.

Is there any possibility to update only "platforms\android\assets\www" via some scripts or cordova CLI.(It's big project and i can't do it manually)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cordova android uses gradle now, if you are not using a gradle compatible version try to update to the latest

Then, you shouldn't write on cordova gradle file, you should create your own:

> Extending build.gradle
>
> If you need to customize build.gradle, rather than edit directly, you
>   should create a sibling file named build-extras.gradle. This file will
>   be included by the main build.gradle when present. Here's an example:

```
    # Example build-extras.gradle
    # This file is included at the beginning of `build.gradle` 
    ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile =
     '../../android-debug-keys.properties'

    # When set, this function allows code to run at the end of `build.gradle` 
    ext.postBuildExtras = {
        android.buildTypes.debug.applicationIdSuffix = '.debug' }
```

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide_platforms_android_tools.md.html

If you do this, your build-extras.gradle file shouldn't be overwritten on prepare

There is no cordova command to just copy the files, in fact, most of them will overwrite your gradle files, so you can't accomplish what you want with a cordova command, but you can create a node script (or .sh/.cmd/.exe) to copy the files

Comment: I don't write on specific android files. my android project needs that file.

Comment: sorry i can't edit. 
duplicate files in git repo aren't create any issue because git handle with it and don't take any more space on repo. but TY for your answer it will be useful in future.